# Comparing x,y to z to see which one is closer

Tags: c#

I'm new to C# and making a small exercise where a user enters a value between 1 and 100 **(x)**. The computer then proceeds to generate a random number to use for the game **(y)** and generates another random number for itself **(z)**.

The program compares the value of x and z to y to see which value is closer to y.
I'm having some trouble doing the comparing stuff. It's more of a logical difficulty than it is coding wise. I'm relatively new so i pretty much suck at naming conventions.

```
class Roll
{
    public int randomNumber { get; set; } //Random number for game
    public int randomPc { get; set; }   //Random number for pc

    private void RandomGenerator() //Generates a number for int randomNumber and randomPc
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        randomNumber = rnd.Next(1, 100);
        randomPc = rnd.Next(1, 100);
    }

    public Roll(int user) //Is where the comparison takes place
    {
        RandomGenerator();
        int compareUser;
        int comparePc;

        compareUser = user - randomNumber; 
        comparePc = randomPc - randomNumber;


        if (compareUser < comparePc)
            Console.WriteLine("\nPC won!\n{0} is closer to {1} than {2} is!", randomPc, randomNumber, user);



        if (comparePc < compareUser)
            Console.WriteLine("\nUser has won!\n{2} is closer to {1} than {0} is!", randomPc, randomNumber, user);


    }

}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your comparison may be negative. Look into comparing the *absolute* value of the difference

Comment: You're going to want to use `Math.Abs` for your values.

Comment: As a side note, you have also missed the case where the players tie (`compareUser == comparePc`)

Comment: what difficulty you are getting? As far as i see your logic is clear.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, could you explain how to use Math.abs in this scenario? EDIT: Figured it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never thought of the case where the `compareUser` result is negative. Therefore, you are going to need to compute `the difference` between the two numbers, like a distance, and not just the math value `user - randomNumber`. We do that using [**Math.Abs()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4ke8e73(v=vs.110).aspx) function.

Also your logic is missing the case were `compareUser` is = `comparePc`

This is how your logic should be:

```
public Roll(int user) //Is where the comparison takes place
{
    RandomGenerator();
    int compareUser;
    int comparePc;

    compareUser = Math.Abs(user - randomNumber); 
    comparePc = Math.Abs(randomPc - randomNumber);


    if (compareUser < comparePc)
        Console.WriteLine("\nPC won!\n{0} is closer to {1} than {2} is!", randomPc, randomNumber, user);

    else if (comparePc < compareUser)
        Console.WriteLine("\nUser has won!\n{2} is closer to {1} than {0} is!", randomPc, randomNumber, user);
    else
    {
       // compareUser == comparePc - do something
    }

}
```